# Exception for the variable type user input

Tags: java, variables

I've got an if statement which accepts integers and i want to use an exception for when the input is anything but an integer value, so basically the users can't enter text when it requires a number. Does anyone know how to do this, would be appreciated! :D I know how to do the exception, just not for checking the variable type
JAVA!

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: java, sorry for not mentioning

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if (x == (int)x)
{
   // Number is integer
}
```